# GoogleApiClient.Builder().addApi() for FCM

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to ensure devices have the Google Play services APK for Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Which API should i add in `.addApi()` and `.addScope()` method for FCM?

For example, if i want to use location service, i add this code in MainActivity:

```
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */,
                      this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
    .build();
```

Also for check Google Drive, i use:

```
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */,
                      this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
    .addApi(Drive.API)
    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
    .build();
```

but i don't know the API and Scope value for FCM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [GoogleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability.html#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(android.content.Context)). If this method returns SUCCESS it means that the Google Services API version that you specified in your `build.gradle` is supported on the device and that the device has the Firebase APIs; you are building your code against this version, which implies that the Firebase APIs that you are using in your code are supported in this version. The system does not need to provision access to the Firebase APIs, which is the purpose of `addApi()`.

You do not need a `GoogleApiClient` to access the Firebase APIs/FCM.